# Rails credentials escaping OpenSSL cipher key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I'm trying to store a raw OpenSSL cipher key inside rails credentials file but, during the retrival, value gets escaped and it's not working anymore when i try to use it as an actual key.

```
# credentials.yml
cipher_key: "\xCC\x7Ft%\xEA\xAD\x15u^\xB9W1\xB2m\x7FDZr\x04C\xE24\x93\xCFz4\x89\x7F-g\xBE5"

# Rails console
3.1.1 :001 > Rails.application.credentials.cipher_key
 => "Ì\u007Ft%ê­\u0015u^¹W1²m\u007FDZr\u0004Câ4\u0093Ïz4\u0089\u007F-g¾5"
```

Is there any way to retrieve the raw value of rails credential?

Comment: Are you sure you're storing the cipher key correctly? never seen escaped values for a cipher key.

Comment: Not sure how to answer that :) I'm editing the file with `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`